# Subversion radio button is not available in Hudson

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I got the latest hudson running in jetty and it has maven 2/3 project type indicated as legacy. When I try to configure the project, there is no "subversion" radio button..Only CVS, git is available.I hear subversion plugin comes default with hudson but then why I don't see the subversion radio button.Am I being stupid or what am I missing?Is there anyway I can install subversion plugin manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if Subversion plugin is installed: enter `http://[hudson_url]/pluginManager/installed` in your browser. Search for *Subversion Plugin*.
If it is there, but the box next to it is unchecked - the plugin is disabled. Check the box and restart Hudson.

If the plugin is not there, enter `http://[hudson_url]/pluginManager/available`, search for *Subversion Plugin*, check the box next to it, go to the bottom of the page and click the *Install* button (you'll probably need to restart Hudson).

If the plugin is there and enabled - please update your question. There is also a slight chance that there is a mismatch between your plugin and your version of Hudson. Goto `http://[hudson_url]/pluginManager/` and see if there is a warning next to *Subversion Plugin*.

Comment: surprisingly, subversion plugin is available in installed plugins list and also the check box is checked. but the radio button is not available. there is no version warnings either... But I used jenkins later, it show svn...So I will go with jenkins

Comment: Yes, Jenkins is much better maintained - if you can go with Jenkins instead of Hudson, by all means do so!